# How to get the latest record from each unique value of key

Tags: elasticsearch, elk

How to get the latest record from each unique value of key combined (in the example which is “combined.keyword”)
I can see the buckets in aggregations, but also wanted a way to get the most recent record for each bucket.

Here is my query:

```
GET /new_csvindex/_search?pretty
{
  "size" : 1,
   "query": {
    "bool" : {
      "must_not":[
      
        {"term": {"combined.keyword" : "combined"}}
        
        ]
    }
  },
    "sort": [
        { "@timestamp":   { "order": "desc" }}
    ],
    "aggs" : {
        "get_the_latest_record_from_each_bucket" : {
        "terms" : { "field" : "combined.keyword", "exclude": [ "combined"]}
         
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please share some sample index data and expected search results?

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for [top_hits](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html) aggregation. Use it as below:

```
{
  "size": 1,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": [
        {
          "term": {
            "combined.keyword": "combined"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "@timestamp": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ],
  "aggs": {
    "get_the_latest_record_from_each_bucket": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "combined.keyword",
        "exclude": [
          "combined"
        ]
      },
      "aggs": {
        "latest": {
          "top_hit": {
            "sort": {
              "@timestamp": "desc"
            },
            "size": 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```